# При выполнении игнорирует изменение пути

Tags: node.js

```
var getSize = require('get-folder-size');
var fs = require('fs');
var myFolder = 'E:\\MyProjects\\NodeJs\\dir_memories';


fs.readdir(myFolder, function(err, items) {
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var file = items[i];


    fs.stat(file, function(nameFile) {
      return function(err, stats) {

        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        if (stats.isFile()) {
          console.log(nameFile + " " + stats["size"]);
        }
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
          getSize(nameFile, function(err, size) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            console.log(nameFile + " " + size );
          });
        }
      }
    }(file));
  }
});
```

[image]

При изменении пути выдает ошибку, работает только в корневой папке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(file)
```

Вероятно, там только имя, а пути нет - вот он потом и ищется рядом с кодом.